# Feed 1 frame to 2 models in tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, parallel-processing, ros

I have two tensorflow models (A.pb, B.pb ).
I have two written two python codes. Both of these take same frame input and produce output. (Currently,  I run both of them in different terminals.)

Since they take same image frame as inputs... Can I do something in tensorflow like:

In 1 single python file :

- Put the both codes in 1 single file.
- Open both A.pb and B.pb models.
- Feed the same input image frame two both A.pb and B.pb parallely
- Superimpose the output of A.pb & B.pb and produce 1 single output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run 2 different models in the same tensorflow file like this:

```
graph_A = tf.Graph()
with graph_A.as_default():
    # create or saver.restore tf variables here for model A

graph_B = tf.Graph()
with graph_B.as_default():
    # create or saver.restore tf variables here for model B


# run model A
session_A = tf.Session(graph=graph_A)    
with session_A.as_default():
    with graph_A.as_default():
        # feed image into model A
        output_A = session_A.run([], feed_dict={})

# run model B
session_B = tf.Session(graph=graph_B)    
with session_B.as_default():
    with graph_B.as_default():
        # feed image into model B
        output_B = session_B.run([], feed_dict={})

# do something with outputs
print(output_A, output_B)
```

If you really want to run the them "parallely" you have to run the sessions in separate threads or subprocesses, but I won't cover that here.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.. yes, but then running both parallely is a must.. using threads... like subprocess in python  is a way.
 Bt as I mentioned earlier.. **Both model A & B take same input image.. If I follow your code then in both the models images have to feed seperately which increases my computation time.**
Is there any work around for feeding same input image to both ?